# Interpret GLM formula as an ecuation

Tags: r, glm

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I am stuck in interpreting glm formula.
I calculated a binomial model and I want to use the formula output (intercept and each of the estimated coefficients) to "manually" calculate the predicted score calculated by the model.
In the case of a linear regression this should be something like

```
y = a +b1*x1+ ... + bn*xn 
or
score = intercept + x.1*variable.1 + ... + x.n* variable.n
```

but I understand that logistic regression is different, and could not find how.

Could someone help me with this?
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I find out that I need to apply the inv.logit transformation, but even aplying it, the value obtained is different from the score calculated by the model ... Still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that the score could be manually calculated aplying the formula as is detailed in teh output and using inv.logit() to the value obtained.